# MailEnable - Create Account

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create an e-mail with MailEnable 
based  http://www.mailenable.com/developers/NET_SignUp.zip

```
 MailEnable.Administration.Login oLogin = new MailEnable.Administration.Login();
        oLogin.Account = iCliente.URL;
        oLogin.LastAttempt = -1;
        oLogin.LastSuccessfulLogin = -1;
        oLogin.LoginAttempts = -1;
        oLogin.Password = txt_Senha.Text;
        oLogin.Rights = "";
        oLogin.Status = -1;
        oLogin.UserName = txt_Email + "@" + iCliente.URL;
        if (oLogin.GetLogin() != 1)
        {
            oLogin.LastAttempt = 0;
            oLogin.LastSuccessfulLogin = 0;
            oLogin.LoginAttempts = 0;
            oLogin.Password = txt_Senha.Text;
            oLogin.Rights = "USER";
            oLogin.Status = 1;
        }

        MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox mailBoxCreate = new MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox();
        mailBoxCreate.Postoffice = iCliente.URL;
        mailBoxCreate.MailboxName = txt_Email.Text;
        mailBoxCreate.RedirectAddress = txt_Redirect.Text;
        mailBoxCreate.RedirectStatus = 0;//recuperar valor da checkbox
        mailBoxCreate.Limit = 51200; //-1 for unlimited
        mailBoxCreate.Status = 1;
        mailBoxCreate.AddMailbox();

        MailEnable.Administration.AddressMap mailAMap = new MailEnable.Administration.AddressMap();
        mailAMap.Account = iCliente.URL;
        mailAMap.DestinationAddress = "[SF:" + iCliente.URL + "/" + txt_Email.Text + "]";
        mailAMap.SourceAddress = "[SMTP:" + txt_Email.Text + "@" + iCliente.URL + "]";
        mailAMap.AddAddressMap();
```

But does not work, it creates the email but no password!
:(

Comment: what type of control is `txt_Senha`?

Comment: txt_senha = TextBox
I think the problem is I try to create the password along with the account and the documentation first creates the account and then change the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow my class running perfect.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using MailEnable;

    namespace BLL
    {
        public class MailEnable_Geral
        {
    public string _Email { get; set; }
       public bool CriarEmail(string _senha, string _redirect, long _ativarRedirect)
            {

                string[] vPostoffice = _Email.Split('@');
                string _username = vPostoffice[0];
                string _postoffice = vPostoffice[1];
                string _domain=_postoffice;

                bool _retorno = true;
                try
                {
                    MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox mb = new MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox();
                    mb.Postoffice = _postoffice;
                    mb.MailboxName = _username;
                    mb.Host = _domain;
                    mb.Limit = 51200;//50MB
                    mb.RedirectAddress = _redirect;
                    mb.RedirectStatus = _ativarRedirect;//Ativa ou desativa Redirect
                    mb.Status = 1;

                    mb.AddMailbox();

                    MailEnable.Administration.Login login = new MailEnable.Administration.Login();
                    login.Account = _postoffice;

                    login.Description = _username + " at " + _domain;
                    login.Host = _domain;
                    login.Rights = "USER";
                    login.Status = 1;
                    login.Password = _senha;
                    login.UserName = _username + "@" + _postoffice;

                    login.AddLogin();

                    MailEnable.Administration.AddressMap map = new MailEnable.Administration.AddressMap();
                    map.Account = _postoffice;
                    map.DestinationAddress = "[SF:" + _postoffice + "/" + _username + "]";
                    map.SourceAddress = "[SMTP:" + _username + "@" + _domain + "]";
                    map.Scope = "";


                    if (map.AddAddressMap() == 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed address map");
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _retorno = false;
                }
                return _retorno;
            }

        }
    }
```